How to Unregister a Core Block Type in Gutenberg
I'm trying to unregister core block types in WordPress Gutenberg using java script and PHP but I couldn't achieve the result.

I created .js file with the using plugin [Simple custom CSS & JS]. The following was the code used

import domReady from '@wordpress/dom-ready';
import { getBlockTypes, unregisterBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

const disallowedBlocks = [
'core/preformatted',
'core/table',
'core/code',
'core/video',
'core/verse',
'core/avatar',
'core/audio',
'core/calendar',
'core/freeform',
];

domReady(() => {
const blocks = getBlockTypes();
blocks.forEach(({ name }) => {
if (disallowedBlocks.includes(name)) {
unregisterBlockType(name);
}
});
});


I then Enqueued the .js file using plugin [Code Snippet]. the code is as follows

function enqueue_custom_block_unregistration_script() {
// Enqueue the JavaScript file
wp_enqueue_script(
'custom-block-unregistration-script', // Handle
'/path/to/js/file', // path to JavaScript file
array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post' ), // Dependencies: WordPress block editor API
false, // Version
true // Load script
);
}
// Hook into the 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' action
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_custom_block_unregistration_script' );

But unfortunately the blocks still exist in Gutenberg Block editor.
Please help to solve this problem
regards!

Have you somehow confirmed that your script is being loaded at all?

Yes, I can confirm that the script is being loaded in the page source.
